# How to avoid unexpected identifier in while loop inside for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

I'm receiving an unexpected identifier inside a while loop. If i remove the while loop i don't receive the unexpected identifier, but in javascript i don't know how to make this code work so i can loop until j is less than y div 2 while increasing y in the while loop

```
function Xploder(num,bits=1) {
  temp = BigInt(num) + BigInt(1)
  xnum = (temp * BigInt(Math.pow(2, bits)))-1n
  return xnum
}

var y = 3n
var j = 1009n
for (x=0; x<1; x++) {
  while ( (j < y//2) ) 
     y=Xploder(y)
}

Thrown:
     y=Xploder(y)
     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
> }
```

How do i format my code so i don't get an unexpected identifier inside the while loop, or in javascript, how do i write the above code correctly.

ANSWERED by the commenters below. I'm switching from python to javascript and just didn't notice that i was commenting out by not changing to normal division that javascript uses. Thanks for the answers, i was able to fix this conversion issue. Thanks again!

Comment: You're not doing `y/2`, you're doing `y//2` which means you're commenting out the second half of that line, breaking your syntax. This is just a typo.

Comment: `y//2` what should that be? Because `//` signifies the start of a comment, so you commented out the rest of the line.

Comment: I would suggest looking carefully at the syntax highlighting your code produced...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're commenting y instead of dividing it.

```
function Xploder(num,bits=1) {
  temp = BigInt(num) + BigInt(1)
  xnum = (temp * BigInt(Math.pow(2, bits)))-1n
  return xnum
}

var y = 3n
var j = 1009n
for (x=0; x<1; x++) {
  while ( (j < y/2) ) 
     y=Xploder(y)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yardenl, i'm switching from python to javascript and it hit me when you answered that yeah, i can't do the same operation, so the single slash version worked for me. Thanks again,

Answer (score 1):

A double forward slash is how you mark the start of a comment, so this:

```
for (x=0; x<1; x++) {
  while ( (j < y//2) ) 
     y=Xploder(y)
}
```

is parsed as this:

```
for (x=0; x<1; x++) {
  while ( (j < y y=Xploder(y)
}
```

... which explains the error message.

If you want to divide, use a single `/`

```
for (x=0; x<1; x++) {
  while (j < y/2) 
     y=Xploder(y)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Will, i'm switching from python to javascript and it hit me when you answered that yeah, i can't do the same operation, so the single slash version worked for me. Thanks again,